# Timing on a pipeline

Tags: computer-architecture, timing

I'm basically reviewing for a test in my computer organization class and there's a question about pipelining. The questions is:

> "If the pipeline consists of 6 stages and each stage executes its task in 2 ns, how long does it take for an individual instruction to execute in the pipelined unit?"

Is the total time 12 ns? I feel as if the answer is far more difficult to get. Can anyone give me an assurance?

Comment: Since pipeline doesn't help to reduce the latency of a single instruction but the throughput of instructions. So I think 12ns would be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a pipeline datapath, then Lets's assume each instruction takes say 10ns. So for 6 instructions it would take 6x10 = 60ns.

with a pipelined datapath having 6 stages with 2ns requirement for each stage, 6 instructions would take <s>12+2+2+2+2+2</s> 2*11 = 22ns. Each instruction takes 12ns but the throughput of instructions has increased.

Attached a figure that I found by googeling:

[image]

Comment: Why is the "first" instruction 12ns instead of 2ns?

Comment: sorry for confusing. Updated the answer. Basically each instruction takes 12ns. 2ns is just the delayed time unit for other instructions.